# Parse and Additional Facebook Permissions (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, permissions, parse-platform

There are two Parse methods for reauthorizing a Facebook User (to gain additional permissions) in Parse (for iOS):

- `reauthorizeUser:withPublishPermissions:audience:block:`
- `reauthorizeUser:withPublishPermissions:audience:target:selector:`

Unfortunately, both of these methods are for `publishPermissions`. I am confused, because it seems that there is no way to add additional read permissions (i.e. Extended Profile Permissions) after the initial login.

Facebook advises that, when doing a general login (i.e. on app opening), you only ask for basic permissions, and then ask for extended permissions as needed, so as not to scare off the user.

So with Parse and Facebook for iOS, does this now mean that we need to ask for every single read permission that we may possibly need at initial login?

Overall it seems that the Parse documentation and framework seems to be lacking a lot of the Facebook instructions for login in various scenarios. We are directed to view the Facebook SDK, but everything there seems to apply to FBSession, and it is not clear which methods are replaced by Parse and which are needed in addition to Parse.

I, for example, have an app where the user can login to Parse via FB on app launch, but does not have to. If they do login, they are asked for only the basic permissions, as advised by FB. Then, should the user try to perform certain actions, they are asked for the permissions for that particular action. I have additional read permissions that need to be granted for the extended profile, as well as publish_actions.

Can anyone give me some direction in this case, or point me too a really thorough, up-to-date, example? The Parse FB Scrumptious example code looked promising to me at first, but it is severely outdated.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same questions. Parse does not give good instructions about how to use its own classes.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are more than one way to do it. The easiest one I found using Parse for Android was like this:

```
   Collection<String> publishPermissions = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
   ParseFacebookUtils.linkWithPublishPermissionsInBackground(user, myActivityOrFragment, publishPermissions, new SaveCallback() {...});
```

Which means that after logging in, you should call linkWithPublishPermissionsInBackground with your user reference and the new permission list. It will open a new Facebook window asking for that permission and link the result to your user.

This code I tested and it works. But seems that Parse is not that smart, some things it does automatically and some it does not. So after that you need to call something like:

```
   ParseFacebookUtilities.linkInBackground(ParseUser, AccessToken)
```

To actually save it to the user on the server, otherwise, it would work only while the App is running.